# How to prevent apps from entering immersive mode in portrait mode?

Tags: notification-bar, immersive-mode, navigation-bar, edxposed

Some games in portrait mode will enter immersive mode automatically, and my navigation bar and notification bar will be hidded, and it is really annoying for me.
Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Root, Magisk and Xposed(Edxposed) is acceptable.

Comment: Do you mean they are hidden even if you swipe up from the bottom? If not, they are designed that way -- they want to be full screen.

Comment: @S.Mitchell No, they will appear If I swipe up from the button, but I want to prevent them from being hidden totally.